# Arch Linux error "Cannot set LC_(CTYPE/MESSAGES/ALL) to default locale: no such file or directory"

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, locale

In my many struggles while installing Arch, I have ran into a problem which I don't seem to be able to solve.

What I am trying to do is execute `locale > /etc/locale.conf` but it returns with the errors above...

I have tried to edit `/root/bash.rc` and add `export LC_MESSAGES` and `export LC_LANG` (i think) to it with the correct values. 
However I still get that problem.

Update: Actual output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory.

locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory.

locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: "locale-gen > /etc/locale.conf" works though... Is that alright? Or do I need "locale"

Comment: 1. please add that actual output in the question.  2. Remember that people are not next to you, be explanative. 3. You may wish to remove the comments about the arch linux forums since they are not helpful to the question.  PS: installing and running Arch is an act of diligence, you might be taking the wrong attitude to it in the first place.

Comment: Okay... 1. Will do 2. What do you want me to explain? 3. They explain why I posted the question here and not on Arch Forums, which helps the reader understand the context of the situation... PS: I DO have the right attitude, but it really shouldn't be THIS tedious a task should it?

Comment: You do need to proper locale files present on the system for it to work, which is the reason for the `locale-gen` script which can handle most locales.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying... Do you mean that I need to do "locale-gen > /etc/locale.conf" or are you saying what the locale-gen does? Explain.

Comment: @UltraLuminous:  `locale_gen` is a script used to create the needed files for your locale.  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/locale-gen.8.html for more details.

Comment: Okay, but how does that help me? I did locale-gen and then "locale > /etc/locale.conf" still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to edit `/etc/locale.conf` manually. Just put a line like `LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8` with your proper locale and you should have generated the locales with `locale-gen` after editing `/etc/locale.gen` with both your locale line and the `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` line (you just have to "uncomment" the lines).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem installing arch linux for the first time.
edit /etc/locale.conf and add your selected locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

edit /etc/locale.gen and uncomment your selected locale!

then run locale-gen

```
# locale-gen
```